# "HDA audio bus driver is required and not found" on Dell Optiplex

Tags: windows, drivers, audio

I have Dell Optiplex 745 with Windows 7 installed on it. I'm trying to use the Windows XP audio driver as Windows 7 drivers aren't available for Optiplex 745 and Windows Vista driver is displaying that it's not compatible with my hardware.

When I try to install the Windows XP audio driver, it's displaying an error

> HDA audio bus driver is required and not found

The installation fails then.

I have researched thourghly and used many drivers but my audio is not working at all. I was also told that it might be a problem with my hardware – that is, a problem with the board.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the Windows Vista Drivers for your sound card instead:

[Tom's Hardware forums proscribe a solution](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/40240-63-sound-drivers-dell-optiplex)

Comment: Thanks for you support but as I mentioned in my question when I try to install windows vista driver, it displays a message that this driver is compatible with your hardware. Also please be noted that windows xp driver was working really nice for some time but after a few days of my windows 7 installation, it stop working and now all this happening as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You may wish to verify that, if your OS is 64-bit, that the 64-bit driver is the one you're using. If your OS is 32-bit, you will require the 32-bit driver.

Comment: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3513/p/19322012/19656540.aspx#19656540 May also be helpful.

HAve you read the full post and replies in my article; there are several alternative processes posted.

Comment: My OS is 32-bit and I have also read this post but my problem still remained unresolved.

Comment: Did you try running the driver installer in compatibility mode? Also, why not use Windows' built-in HiDef audio driver?

Answer (score 0):

1. reboot
2. go into the Dell BIOS (should be the F2 key)
3. make sure that the integrated audio is enabled